# Proving that there exists a vector that makes a linear system inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I encountered this problem in one of my linear algebra homeworks (Linear Algebra with Applications 5th Ed 1.3.44):

Consider a $n \times m$ matrix $A$, such that $n > m$. Show there is a vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that the system $Ax=b$ is inconsistent.

I have a strong intuition as to why this is true, because the transformation matrix maps a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so it is going from a lower dimension to a higher. When the $m$ components in $x$ vary, they would at most be parameterizing an $m$-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. However, my "proof" (which is included below, feels very handwavey and sloppy. It may also be incorrect in a number of places. I'd appreciate it if I could get some pointers on how to formalize proofs of this type a little more, so they are rigorous enough to write on a homework/test, and maybe an example with this example.

My proof:

Consider the case where $A$ has at least $m$ linearly independent row-vectors. Using elementary row operations, rearrange $A$ to $A'$, so these $m$ row vectors are the first $m$ rows. $b'$ will refer to the vector $b$ under the same rearrangement of rows. If we place the first $m$ rows in reduced row ecchelon form using only elementary operations with the first $m$ rows, the augmented matrix $[A'|b']$ will have the following form, where $x_{i}$ is the $i$-th element of the solution vector $x$.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  & \dots  & 0 & x_{1} \\
    0 & 1  & \dots  & 0 & x_{2}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & \dots  & 1 & x_{m} \\
    a'_{m+1, 1} & a'_{m+1, 2} & \dots & a'_{m+1, m} & b'_{m+1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    a'_{n,1} & a'_{n, 2} & \dots & a'_{n,m} & b'_{n}
\end{bmatrix}

Now consider the $m+1$th row. To eliminate coefficients in this row, it would mean that $x_{m+1} = b'_{m+1} - $$\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i}\cdot a_{m+1,i}$, because to eliminate each coefficient would involve scaling by $a_{m+1,i}$ and then subtracting. The system is inconsistent for all $x_{m+1} \neq 0$, so we then choose any $b'_{m+1}$ for which this inequality holds, there are infinitely many, to find $b'$ which makes $A'x=b'$ inconsistent. Then, unswap the rows to make our $b'$ back into $b$ and we have found a vector which makes our system inconsistent.

Comment: Depending on what you can use: Assume no such $b$ exists. Then for each standard base vector $e_i$, $1\le i\le n$, we find at least one $x_i\in \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax_i=e_i$. If $\sum c_ix_i=0$ for some numbers $c_i$, then $$\sum c_ie_i=\sum c_iAx_i=\sum Ac_ix_i=A\sum c_ix_i=A0=0.$$
As the $e_i$ are linearly independent, we conclude that all $c_i$ are $=0$. This shows that the $n$ vectors $x_i\in \Bbb R^m$ are linearly independent, contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure your argument like this. First, let $\bar{A}$ be the row-reduced Echelon form of $A$, so that
$$\bar{A} = E_1 E_2\cdots E_k A$$
for elementary row operations $E_k$.

1) Can you exhibit a concrete $\bar{b}$ for which the row-reduced system $\bar{A}x = \bar{b}$ has no solution?

2) Can you use the answer to (1) to construct a $b$ for which $Ax=b$ has no solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: how many pivot positions can the reduced echelon form of $A$ have? What does this say about the rank of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As a different approach, the equation $Ax=b$ has a solution (i.e., is consistent) iff $b$ is an element of the column space (range) of $A$. What can you say about the dimension of this space?